# if horizontal, it makes two side-by-side copies

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

In vertical orientation, this basic layout is fine. But in horizontal orientation, two copies of the layout are generated. Any hints about what might cause this?

[image: In vertical orientation, this basic layout is fine.]

[image: But in horizontal orientation, two copies of the layout are generated. Any hints about what might cause this?]

Thanks in advance... puzzled, I'm still getting oriented to the Xcode interface.

- No custom code yet, this is all done via the Xcode GUI.
- I've added a screenshot showing the constraints.
  [image: The simple scene and constraints are shown here.]

Comment: We have no way of telling from a screenshot. You need to post information about your storyboard, constraints, and any custom code you're using to create it. You might also try using view debugging to figure out what's going ont.

Comment: _Thanks, Duncan._ I just added a third screenshot, hoping it provides something helpful! No custom code yet, this was done via the GUI.

Comment: And what about your size classes? Have you added the same view objects in multiple size classes? How do you get from your root view controller to your data view controller? Have you set a breakpoint in your DataViewController's init or viewDidLoad method to see if it's getting called twice?

Answer (score 0):

Because there were no duplicate elements and zero logic in place yet, the issue was likely more fundamental. So we started with RootViewController.swift and found that some action or setting had inserted a custom pageViewController. Sure enough, it was creating two view controllers when in landscape orientation, as the following code comment describes:

`// In landscape orientation: Set the spine location to "mid" and the page view controller's view controllers array to contain two view controllers. If the current page is even, set it to contain the current and next view controllers; if it is odd, set the array to contain the previous and current view controllers.`

We commented out the code that had been inserted and the issue is resolved.